# Splitting a string in Java only when a delimiter is surrounded by quote marks

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Let's say I have the following string:

```
"John Doe","IT,SI","foo, bar"
```

And I would like to split it into:

```
["John Doe", "IT,SI", "foo, bar"]
```

I was thinking to implement something like this:

```
String line = "\"John Doe\",\"IT,SI\",\"foo, bar\"";
String[] lineItems = line.split("\",\"");

for (String lineItem : lineItems) {
    lineItem.removeAll("\"");
}
```

It does the thing, however this doesn't seem to be a state of art. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Use CSV parser please.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Below regex  works well for this case.

```
String[] lineItems = line.split("(?<=\"),(?=\")");
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should solve the issue

```
line.split("(?<=\"),(?=\")")
```

Answer (score 0):

You wants the words between double quotes so instead of splitting the string you can use following regex to extract them :

```
/"([^"]+)"/g
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/hC3cW2/1

Answer (score 0):

```
(\b[^"]+)
```

Or you may name it also:

```
(?P<names>\b[^"]+)
OR
(?<names>\b[^"]+)
```

Not sure java supports P<> or <>